# Add "0" to number in strings if they have two digits only

Tags: python

Lets say, I have this array:

```
s = ["data_s01", "data_s99", "data_s133"]
```

I want to add "0" after "s" if there are only two digits. so the result is:

```
["data_s001", "data_s099", "data_s133"]
```

I have this now:

```
for v in s:
    data = v.split('_s')  
    if "0" in data:
        out_s = data[0] + "0" + data[1]
        print(out_s)
```

But nothing is printed?

Comment: `"0"` will never be in `data` unless you have `"data_s0"`. You want to see if `"0"` is in `data[1]`. But as Scott Hunter says, it's irrelevant if `"0"` is inside, what matters is that `len(data[1]) == 2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> ["data_s{:0>3}".format(x[6:]) for x in s]
['data_s001', 'data_s099', 'data_s133']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
x=["data_s01", "data_s99", "data_s133"]
print ["".join(["data_s",k.split("_s")[1].zfill(3)]) for k in x]
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

The `print` function should not be inside the `if`, since only original strings with no `0` would get printed.  Then again, I don't know why you care if there is a `0` in there or not.